# MS-Access active username autofill textbox

Tags: ms-access-2003

Is there and Access equivalent to excel code Application.UserName to auto fill a text box as a default value?

Based on Feedback From HansUp I have modified as follows

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.LastChgUser = Excel.Application.UserName
End Sub
```

As my Load event for the form. I now receive a Compile Error: Method or Data Member Not found.  THe Txt box "LastChgUser" is on a subform "Staffing" as part form "Associate Lookup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access' `CurrentUser()` function returns the Access security account name, which will be "Admin" unless you have set up user-level security.

You can use the Windows API to get the name of the current Windows user.  Try the `fOSUserName()` function from [Get Login name](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm).

Another alternative is the `Environ()` function:

```
? Environ("USERNAME")
hans
```

Although that approach is insecure, it may be adequate for your purpose: load a default value which the user will be allowed to change.  However, security settings may not allow you to use it directly as the control source for a text box.

Comment: Hans, I am trying to use the =ExcelUser() as that seems to be the option with the least possibility for trouble. Should I reference the code as an after update event?

Comment: I have modified the OP with the results and new eror.

Comment: It works for me with Access 2007 and only a different text box name, so I don't understand what's wrong.  I would use the `fOSUserName()` function instead because I'd rather add a custom function than a reference.

Comment: @DesertSpider Since `Excel.Application.UserName` didn't work for you, I removed it from the answer.  Although it worked for me, it doesn't seem like it's a useful suggestion because I don't understand enough about the details to make it work generally.